# String and Number - Mismatched Aggregation

Tags: calculated-field, amazon-quicksight

I have this table:

```
Genres             Episodes   

Drama                2
Drama                1
Drama                0
Comedy               2
Comedy               1
Comedy               0
Kids                 3
Kids                 2
Kids                 1
Kids                 0
```

I want to create a calculated field:

```
Genres             Episodes            Criteria

Drama                2                  Complete
Drama                1                  Partial
Drama                0                  Obsolete
Comedy               2                  Complete
Comedy               1                  Partial
Comedy               0                  Obsolete
Kids                 3                  Complete
Kids                 2                  Partial
Kids                 1                  Partial
Kids                 0                  Obsolete
```

My calculated field formula throws an error:

```
ifelse({Genres} = 'Drama' and (count({Episodes}) = 2), 'Complete',
{Genres} = 'Drama' and (count({Episodes}) = 0), 'Obsolete',
{Genres} = 'Drama' and (count({Episodes}) = 1), 'Partial',
{Genres} = 'Comedy' and (count({Episodes}) = 2), 'Complete',
{Genres} = 'Comedy' and (count({Episodes}) = 0), 'Obsolete',
{Genres} = 'Comedy' and (count({Episodes}) = 1), 'Partial',
{Genres} = 'Kids' and (count({Episodes}) = 3), 'Complete',
{Genres} = 'Kids' and (count({Episodes}) = 0), 'Obsolete','Partial')
```

Error:

```
Mismatched Aggregation. Custom Aggregations cannot contain both aggregate Count and non-Aggregated fields.
```

Can someone help me with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone runs into this issue of mismatched aggregation, I found a workaround.

Simply convert the string into a numerical format (formula) as I did:

```
genres_numbers:    

ifelse({Genres} = 'Drama',1, {Genres} = 'Comedy',2, 3)
```

Secondly, create a `count` formula for the Episodes column:

```
count_episodes:

count({Episodes})
```

Afterwards, take the average of the both and assign the Criteria values as:

```
ifelse(avg({genres_numbers}) = 1 and avg({count_episodes}) = 2, 'Complete'...)
```

This worked for me :)